# Two-level ruleset combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Maybe it doesn't make sense, but what I mean by that is this:

Imagine $n$ types of balls, where for each the availability is defined. There are boxes, each box has its rules.

A box can define:

- min, and max amount of balls that can be inside it
- the types of balls that can be inside it

  - for each type of ball, the min, and max amounts that can be inside it

The problem to solve is given a box, its rules, and the available balls, **how many times we can fill** the box (order doesn't matter, but a combination affects remaining available combinations)?

This seemed like an easy and straightforward problem to solve until I started trying to solve it.
Let me show some examples:

```
{
  minBalls: 2,
  maxBalls: 2,
  ballTypes: [
    { type: 'gray', min: 1, max: 1, available: 2 },
    { type: 'blue', min: 1, max: 1, available: 4 },
  ]
}
```

This is the easiest case because there is only one combination. We have to use both available types. We can fill this type of box 2 times because once we used all the `gray` balls, even though we have 2 `blue` left, we can't validate the box anymore because it needs a `gray` ball as well.

Another case is:

```
{
  minBalls: 1,
  maxBalls: 1,
  ballTypes: [
    { type: 'gray', min: 0, max: 1, available: 2 },
    { type: 'blue', min: 0, max: 1, available: 4 },
  ]
}
```

This box can be filled 6 times, 2 times with `gray`, 4 times with `blue`.

A slightly more complicated case:

```
{
  minBalls: 2,
  maxBalls: 2,
  ballTypes: [
    { type: 'gray', min: 0, max: 1, available: 2 },
    { type: 'blue', min: 1, max: 2, available: 4 },
  ]
}
```

In this case the following events can happen:

- gray: 1, blue: 1, gray left: 1, blue left: 3

  - gray: 0, blue: 2, gray left: 1, blue left: 1

    - gray: 1, blue: 1, gray left: 0, blue left: 0
  - gray: 1, blue: 1, gray left: 0, blue left: 2

    - gray: 0, blue: 2, gray left: 0, blue left: 0
- gray: 0, blue: 2, gray left: 2, blue left: 2

  - gray: 0, blue: 2, gray left: 2, blue left: 0
  - gray: 1, blue: 1, gray left: 1, blue left: 1

    - gray: 1, blue: 1, gray left: 0, blue left: 0

Honestly I have no idea how many times should this be counted.

At the highest level there are really two combinations to fill the box. So at each step we have two options to choose from. And depending on the availability of the balls, we choose one or the another in all possible combinations until there's no more balls left.

- overall there are 9 combinations, however not in the same "timeline"
- the best we can do in the same "timeline" is 3 boxes filled, and even that has 3 combinations
- the worst we can do is 2 boxes, and that has one combination

For the purpose of mine, as long as the availability change of a `ballType` changes the amount of times a box can be filled, I'm happy.

Manually writing down the possible cases if all the numbers are known is easy with small availabilities, and not many ball types. However, if `minBalls`, `maxBalls`, and even `ballTypes` are unknown, it's not possible, and wouldn't be a too effective way anyways.

I tried to write a script, and my approach so far is (wrong, but here it is):

- try to fill the box with required balls first, subtract the sum of `min` values of each `ballTypes` from `minBalls`
- for each `ballTypes`, divide `availability` with `min`, and save the smallest of those to a variable called `requiredBallsCoverBox` (this many times we can fill the box with the required balls)
- for each `ballTypes`, subtract the `min` value from `max`, and `availability` (assigning the required balls have only one way)
- the rest is calculating the above - how many times a box can be filled (don't know how), and save it to a variable `timesBoxCanBeFilledWithOptionalBalls`
- multiply `timesBoxCanBeFilledWithOptionalBalls` with `requiredBallsCoverBox`, and this is the `timesBoxCanBeFilled`

Not just the above misses calculating the main thing (calculating how many times a box can be filled), but the above operation can be quite expensive computationally. I have a feeling that it can be written in a single equation/function. The only requirement is above: **a change in a ball's availability must change the amount of how many times the box can be filled**.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm stuck for days with this. I tried to be as detailed as possible, but if something is not clear, just ask me to edit the question.

Comment: This looks similar to the (number of solutions of the) "knapsack problem" (which is NP-complete, thus expensive to solve!). Maybe, your question has higher chances to be proficiently answered at cs.stackexchange.com  . For small numbers, you could generate all legal combinations, extract the state of the specific box and save it in a set (to automatically avoid duplicates).

Comment: Yes, that looks like a too expensive equation for my case.  The above in my case can go n in depth. And n in width (a box can contain boxes, unknown amount). Also it may have to calculated very often. It’s difficult to define even what is a good enough indicator that confirms that any change in a ball’s availability changes the boxes availability. I would need the cheapest possible option that can meet the above requirement. So I’m not tied to the solution above